# Can't sort array containing int

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm unable to sort an array containing int. Here's my code for the sort :

```
var asr = [];

function sortNumber(a, b) {
  return b - a;
}
asr.sort(sortNumber);
```

The function `sort` doesn't do anything, here is a sample of my array when I made a `console.log(asr)` on chrome :

> by: 3
>   de: 2
>   ds: 14
>   sr: 2
>   vi: 1
>
> **proto**: Array(0)

Comment: You don't have an array, you have an object. You can't sort objects.

Comment: Can you post the original array - if that's an array - called `asr` what you have in the code? Thanks!

Comment: @Pointy Why does `console.log(asr.constructor.name == "Array");` return me `true` then ?

Comment: My guess is that you take an array, but then you attach properties to it as an object (arrays in JS are objects as well). Something like `var asr = []; asr.by = 3; asr.de = 2; // etc...`

Comment: @norbitrial I'm using value from poperties of objects to fill it but at first I declare it like an array : `var asr = [];`

Comment: you've been answered. it's an object. try to sort  Object.values(arr)

Comment: Please show how you define and initialize `asr`.

Comment: @OriDrori Yeah I think that I have been confused because we can also call object properties like an array i.e `asr[by]`

Comment: Arrays in JS are also objects, and you can freely attach values to string keys. But the `sort` method won't touch those, it will just affect the integer keys ("indices").

Comment: this is because your array is empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

Answer (score 3):

Based on your recent update, it seems `asr` is an array with properties you've added. That's not generally a good idea unless you know what you're doing, and `sort()` won't touch those properties.

Instead, I would use a normal object, with the caveat that objects in JavaScript aren't really meant to contain an ordered collection of values. With that caveat out of the way, this is how I'd store the data, and how I'd sort the keys:

```js
const asr = {by: 3, ds: 14, de: 2, vi: 1, sr: 2}

console.log(
Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(asr).sort(
    ([ak, av], [bk, bv]) => av > bv ? 1 : -1
  )
)
)
```

I'll keep the rest here, even though it isn't relevant to your question.

`asr` is most likely an array of objects, in which case `asr.sort()` has sorted the array by the result of the contained objects' `toString` method:

```js
const asr = [{vi: 1}, {sr: 2}, {by: 3}, {ds: 14}, {de: 2}]

console.log(asr.sort())
```

If you want to sort it by object values, this will do the trick:

```js
const asr = [{vi: 1}, {sr: 2}, {by: 3}, {ds: 14}, {de: 2}]

console.log(asr.sort(
  (a, b) => Object.values(a)[0] > Object.values(b)[0] ? 1 : -1
))
```

If you want to sort by object keys, this should work:

```js
const asr = [{vi: 1}, {sr: 2}, {by: 3}, {ds: 14}, {de: 2}]

console.log(asr.sort(
  (a, b) => Object.keys(a)[0] > Object.keys(b)[0] ? 1 : -1
))
```

Comment: Thanks and what If I got object of objects instead of array of objects for sorting by object values ?

Comment: @Diamonds It depends on what you want the final result to look like. Do you want to end up with an array of objects? An object of objects?

Comment: Object of objects because I need the keys to identify each part

Comment: @Diamonds I've added another snippet and some thoughts at the top of this answer.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work with all of my datas while It has the same format as the example..

Comment: The format you have is suspect. It seems you may be confused about how arrays and their methods work. Array methods work on the contents of an array, like `[4,3,2,1].sort() // -> [1,2,3,4]`. Those methods (e.g. `forEach` and `sort`) will ignore any properties you have added to the array.

Comment: Yeah I know I have corrected my code by using only objects with no confusion with array but still..

Answer (score 0):

Your sort function is correct, check with: `console.log([51,2,13,4,5].sort(function(a,b) {return b-a}));`

`asr` doesn't seem to be an array but an object.

Answer (score 0):

Properties in arrays remain in the order that you define them, if you want to have them sorted then you need to define them sorted from the beginning, that being said you can get all the properties of your array, sort the values for this properties from your array and insert this sorted properties into a new array.

```js
const asr = []; 

asr.by = 3; 
asr.de = 2; 
asr.ds = 14;
asr.sr = 2;
asr.vi = 1;

function sortNumber(a, b) {
  return b - a;
}

let asr2 = [...asr];

Object.keys(asr)
    .map(key => ({ key, value: asr[key] }))
    .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value)
    .forEach(a => asr2[a.key] = a.value);


console.log(asr2)

/* 
  // if asr contains values and you also 
  // want to sort those values you need 
  // to sort them separately

  asr2 = asr2.sort((a, b) => b - a)
  console.log(asr2)
*/
```

If what you what is to keep the properties in the same position but sort only the values then try this

```js
const asr = []; 

asr.by = 3; 
asr.de = 2; 
asr.ds = 14;
asr.sr = 2;
asr.vi = 1;

function sortNumber(a, b) {
  return b - a;
}

const asrKeys = Object.keys(asr);

const asrSortedValues =  asrKeys.map(key => asr[key])
                          .sort((a, b) => b - a);

asrKeys.forEach((key, index) => asr[key] = asrSortedValues[index]);


console.log(asr)
```

Comment: With my full data everything is fine, data are sorted well, but when it comes to the `.forEach` `asr2` is the same as `asr`

Comment: This is because `foreach` (and other and other `Array.prototype` methods like `map`, `reduce` and `sort`) will ignore your added properties.